# Can I create the request scoped bean for aspectj?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have an aspect component bean which as per spring gets created as a singleton object. As there is some state maintained in the object, it is not working properly in concurrency scenario. I am aware that it is bad design to maintain the state in spring bean, but due to some design this has been continued. So to resolve this, I was thinking about creating the aspect bean in request bean, and I have used the below scope annotation to do that. But it is still not creating the object per request. So is it that it is not possible to create it in request scope?

```
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```